# jquery username validation rules: no characters except dot

Tags: jquery, html

i got this form that works almost well until i now realised that users can add slashes and other chars to their username, how can i add a rule to prevent that in my validation code

jquery validator

```
$('document').ready(function()
{ 
 /* validation */
 $("#register-form").validate({
  rules:
  {
        full_name: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 3
        },
        user_name: {
        required: true, 
        minlength: 3
        }, 

   },
   messages:
   {

        full_name: "please enter your full name",

         user_name:{
                  required: "please enter your username",
                  minlength: "username must be more than than 3  characters"
                 },


   },
   submitHandler: submitForm    
   });
```

Much thanks for any effort

Comment: I would probably use regex comparison.

Answer (score 3):

You can include the [additional-methods.js](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/additional-methods.js) file and use the `alphanumeric` rule. This will only allow letters, numbers and underscores.

```
$('#register-form').validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      alphanumeric: true
    }
  }
});
```

or if you dont want to include that file. Just copy out the `alphanumeric` method from there.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("alphanumeric", function(value, element) {
return this.optional(element) || /^\w+$/i.test(value);}, "Letters, numbers, and underscores only please");
```

Comment: will the first example accept dots, like  john.doe  . i need something like that, letters numbers and dots

Comment: Just modify the `.addMethod` regex to allow periods. `/^\w.+$/`

Comment: I don't know how to implement that regex into my code ....@ username rule